# Storing user input into a register ARM Assembly Language

Tags: linux, assembly, arm

new/still learning ARM Assembly Language for Linux.
My assignment is to prompt the user for an integer(s) until -1 is entered. If -1 is entered, then the program will end.
How do I store the users integer into a register to compare if it is a -1.
I have this but I get an error, "immediate expression requires a # prefix -- "mov r0, [input]"

.text
.global main

main:

```
# Save return to os on stack
SUB sp, sp, #4
STR lr, [sp, #0]

# Prompt for input
LDR r0, =prompt
BL printf

# Scanf
LDR r0, =input
LDR r1, =num
BL scanf

# Compare user number with -1 (if r0 = -1)
MOV r0, [input]
MOV r1, #-1
CMP r1, r0

# Return to the OS
LDR lr, [sp, #0]
ADD sp, sp, #4
MOV pc, lr
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please read [ask] and take our [tour].  Please also note that pictures of code are not allowed on this site and make it harder to help you.  Please [edit] your question and replace the picture with code as text.

Comment: Also, to help you further, please state what operating system and assembler you are programming for.  If you don't know, please say so, we can help you figure out.

Comment: As for you error message, `mov` does not take a memory operand.  Did you perhaps want to use `ldr` or `str`?

Comment: @fuz sorry, also new to this website. I took off my image and replaced with code. My teacher is having us a raspberry pi, i don't know what operating system it is. Unless there is another way to find out! I'm trying to write this in ARM Assembly.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23833/how-can-i-tell-what-version-of-linux-im-using

Comment: @Martheen after seeing this article, I typed in the command into my raspberry pi and got "Linux raspberrypi 5.10.103-v7+ #1529 SMP Tue Mar 8 12:21:37 GMT 2022 armv7l GNU/Linux" as the output.

Comment: @PriscillaSabik Thanks, I've added the appropriate tags.

Comment: Update that info to your question

Comment: Looking at the code (it's incomplete, make sure to always post complete code so others can assemble and run it to reproduce your error!), you want something like `ldr r0, =input` to load the address and then `ldr r0, [r0]` to load the input.

Answer (score 0):

The `mov` instruction cannot be used to load from memory, it's only for moving between registers (e.g. `mov r1, r2`) or loading immediates (e.g. `mov r0, #42`).  Use a `ldr` instruction to load the user input from memory after having loaded the address:

```
# load the address of input into R0
ldr r0, =input

# load the value of the variable input into R0
ldr r0, [r0]
```